# Jquery Webcam Stop/Closed

Tags: jquery, html5-video

Jquery Webcam Stop/Closed not pause

```
$("#face-login").on('click',function () {

      document.getElementById("face-login").style.display = 'none';



        var canv = document.getElementById("prev"),
      context = canv.getContext("2d"),
      video = document.getElementById("video"),
      localstream = null;
      freq = 10;
      canv.width = 200;//window.innerWidth ;//  800;
      canv.height = 200;//window.innerHeight;// 400;
      context.width = canv.width;
      context.height = canv.height;
      function loadCam(stream) {
        localstream = stream;
        try{
            video.srcObject = stream;
        }catch(error){
            video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }

        logger("Camera loaded [OKAY]");
      }
      function loadFail(stream) {
        logger("Failed loading camera");
      }
      function viewVideo(video, context) {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, context.width, context.height);
        socket.emit("stream", canv.toDataURL("image/webp"));
      }
      $(function() {
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                           navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                           navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        if(navigator.getUserMedia) {
          navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, loadCam, loadFail);
        }
        var duration = 60 * 0.2;//
        var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
        var faceStream = setInterval(function() {
          viewVideo(video, context);
          minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
          seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
          minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
          seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
          if (--timer < 0) {
            clearInterval(faceStream);
            document.getElementById("face-login").style.display = 'inline-block';
            video.pause();
            video.src = "";
            localstream.getTracks()[0].stop();
            timer = duration;
            document.getElementById("video").style.display = 'none';

            location.href="admin";

          }
          logger("Recognizing in: " + minutes + ":" + seconds);
        }, freq*10);

      });
```

location.href="admin";

When you enter the admin panel there also works camera.

I need to turn off the camera. It doesn't stop

error I received.........................................................

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable